# EACCES (Permission denied) on Android 6, with permission granted

Tags: android, permissions, android-sdcard, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to save a `ResponseBody` on an external `SdCard`, but I get the following error:

```
 java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
 at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
 at my.app.package.utils.DocumentFileUtils.saveDocument(DocumentFileUtils.java:120)
```

This is the method that fails:

```
public static String saveDocument(String filename, ResponseBody responseBody) {
    Logs.document("Saving file " + filename);
    File file = createFile(filename);
    Logs.document("Full path: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.getParentFile()
                .mkdirs();
            file.createNewFile(); //Exception happens here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    try {
        BufferedSource source = responseBody.source();
        BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(file));

        sink.writeAll(source);
        sink.close();
        responseBody.close();
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        responseBody.close();
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The file created with createFile has this path:

```
/mnt/media_rw/0123-4567/Android/data/my.app.package/files/document_files/file_name.ext
```

I have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission both in the `Manifest` and as a **runtime permission**, the permission is granted (I can also check that from the app info).

Am I missing something?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: No, I did chose a different route, I can't remember which one.

Comment: This strange behavior at times happens only in the emulator and not real device.